# Error while login to docusign

Tags: docusign

I am getting the attached error so please give the steps how to resolve it. I have purchased the docusign product but still receiving the error.

Thanks [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNx9Y.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message states it clearly

- You need to login into https://www.docusign.net/member/MemberLogin.aspx.
- If you are the administrator you need to enable the mentioned settings above for this user **jeff@netlinkmarketing.com**
- Also make sure whether you are selecting the **Sandbox** option in Environment if its a test instance of DocuSign

I tried connecting similarly and it worked for me.